# Adding multiple objects to ArrayList using loop, all objects get updated when one is changed

Tags: java, for-loop, object, arraylist

I have been using a for loop to create and add new Graph objects to an ArrayList for use elsewhere in my code, but when I print the list all of the Graph objects inside are identical.

An edit to one of the objects follows through on the rest. When I use the debugger to check what is going on each newGraph has a different ID so I have no idea why this is occurring. Code is below. I have included enough so that it is testable.

```
public class Graph {
    int[][] A;
    public static final int graphSize = 5;
  
    public Graph() {
        A = new int[graphSize][graphSize];
    }
    public Graph(Graph another) {
        this.A = another.A;
    }

//This is where the problem is, everything else is so it would run if tested.
    public List<Graph> getAllPossibleGraphs(int playerTurn) {
        List<Graph> possibleGraphs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < graphSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < graphSize; j ++) {
                if (i != j && 0 == this.A[i][j]) {
                    Graph newGraph = new Graph(this);
                    newGraph.insertLine(i, j, playerTurn);
                    possibleGraphs.add(newGraph);
                }
            }
        }
        return possibleGraphs;
    }

    public void insertLine(int node1, int node2, int player) {
            this.A[node1][node2] = player;
            this.A[node2][node1] = player;
    }
    public void printGraph() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Graph.graphSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Graph.graphSize; j++) {
                System.out.print(this.A[i][j] + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph G = new Graph();
        G.insertLine(0, 1, 1);
        List<Graph> testList = G.getAllPossibleGraphs(2);
        testList.forEach(graph -> graph.printGraph());
    }
}
```

So when I print out the list I get all of the Graphs as follows:

```
0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 0,
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated as I have been trying to get a solution to this for over a week and it's driving me insane.

Comment: Need to see the Graph's constructor that's being used. If modifications to one object is also happening to others, then it sounds like all variables are pointing to the same reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have added the constructor to the above information. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks again for taking the time to have a look and comment.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], most likely you are using static fields instead of instance fields.

Comment: Thanks, I have added more so that people can test it out but it seems rather long so I don't know if that is ok - still rater new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sharing A, but probably need a copy. Admittedly I do not understand the logic (too hot).

```
public Graph(Graph another) {
    this();
    for (int i = 0; i < Graph.graphSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Graph.graphSize; j++) {
            A[i][j] = another.A[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```